# Open Android app through deep link if it's installed or fall back to web if not installed

Tags: javascript, android, deep-linking

I'm trying to create a web page that automatically opens an Android app but only if app is installed. In case it's not it should redirect to another web page.

The app is already in production and is properly handling deep links like `example://content?id=42`. The format of the link could not be changed.

### What I've already tried

1) Redirects and timeout:

```
window.location.replace('example://content?id=42');
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.replace = 'http://example.com/content?id=42';
}, 500);
```

Works fine for iOS but for Android it redirects to `example://` immediately and thus gives me `ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`. Seems to be no go for Android.

2) `iframe` approach. [Impossible in rencent Chrome versions](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents). Also doesn't seem to work in Samsung browser.

3) [Intents](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) with `S.browser_fallback_url`. Works well but in Chrome only. Doesn't work in Opera and Samsung browser... most probably nowhere else but Chrome 25+.

Comment: So overall it seems there's no bulletproof solution that covers Samsung browsers. And since their market share is quite significant, it's not a good idea to use deeplinks + web fallback for Android overall if you're not 100% sure user has the app already.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be aware of the browser of the client, and its operating system and adapt your site to them. For example, if the browser is Chrome and the OS is Android, use the Intent solution; if the browser is Safari use the example:// schema. You can get the info looking at the User-Agent header of the request, but I'm sure there are many open source libraries that can help you to get infos related to browser and OS.

Comment: That sounds OK as a general approach. I haven't found a way to do it for Android Samsung phones native browser which seems to be huge. Just checked Twitter implementation. They haven't solved it as well.

Comment: The Chrome intent should work on Samsung browser. Except the fallback URL. Try it!

Comment: My biggest problem is fallback URL. If app is not yet installed, people with Samsung browser will get an error page and that basically means any Samsung phone/tablet newcomers (quite significant number for the project I'm searching solution for) will be lost. Probably forever.

Comment: Il you don't provide the fallback URL the browser should open the play stare searching for the app. Have you tried it? Isn't it enough?

Comment: The whole idea is to get to fallback URL, not to appstore.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could at least approximate the experience by letting the user give a one-time assist:

1. Have your web page itself have the fallback url content.
2. When the page is hit check the user agent to see if the os is Android
3. If its Android, show the user a choice prompt/dialog to use web or Android
4. If they choose web (remember the choice with local storage), dismiss the dialog and show the fallback
5. If they choose android (remember the choice), redirect to the app with the intent:// URL (without fallback_url), will take them to market to install if necessary

After the first interaction, it'll work as you describe - automatically taking them to the web page or the installed app.

Answer (score 0):

use `http://example.com/content?id=42` as the link and add the intent filter to your activity in manifest

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" />
    ...
</intent-filter>
```

However, a list of app registered, e.g. browsers, will show up when the link is first accessed on the machine.

Comment: The app is already released and the deeplink format is defined. I cannot change that because it would break compatibility with older versions.

Comment: ic, I am sorry I can't think of better solution.

Comment: No need to be sorry. That would be a good enough solution for brand new app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this scheme(to be sent to the user):

intent://details?id=X&url=Y&referrer=Z#Intent;scheme=market;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;package=com.android.vending;end";

X: Package name of the App

Y: Deep link scheme which should be defined in the App's manifest.
(Please refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html))
Here, they have used this URL as an example: "http://www.example.com/gizmos" , therefore Y should be replaced by this  URL.

Z: Can be any data which you want to pass to the App via Google Play.
Please take note that any data which you pass should not be '&' separated because the original parameters are itself '&' separated.

PS: The Google Play makes a broadcast to the app. So make sure you receive the broadcast in a receiver.